# phpseclib to connect to pull data from an a10 load balancer

Tags: phpseclib

I am building a remote API that is going to pull data from an A10 loadbalancer via SSH and serve it up to a web front-end in JSON format. I am preferable to the phpseclib library as I have used it for similar things but with other devices(rhel servers,cisco routers etc.).  Here is the thing,  A10 load balancers are serving up some command line syntax issues when I have tried phpseclib's $ssh->exec("show gslb service-ip");

I am not intricately schooled on A10 load balancer command line syntax to know exactly where to look for the issue.

I have also installed sshpass on my server to do some testing and it returns the same thing so I am not sure what the problem is as Google has turned up nothing.  It may be an easy modification of the phpseclib ?  a simple one liner hack?  Help!

```
<?php 
    include_once("phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php");
    $ssh = new Net_SSH2("<a10 load balancer ip>");
    if(!$ssh->login("<username>","<password>")) {
        echo 0;
    } else {
        echo "Pulling configuration...";
        echo $ssh->exec("show gslb service-ip");
    }
?>
```

Here is my return when i exec from command line

```
[root@<servername> php]# php controller.php
Pulling configuration...
/a10/bin/rimacli: invalid option -- c
[root@<servername> php]#
```

A google search for "/a10/bin/rimacli: invalid option -- c" doesnt come up with much as I am sure this is just an option/syntax command line thing that is rarely seen by A10 load balance users.

What is different about the SSH to an A10?  HELP :)

Comment: I guess you figured out an alternative approach lol but I'm almost wondering if maybe it'd work better if PTY was enabled (which you can do via `enablePTY()`). Alternatively, it might work better on an interactive shell. eg. `read()` / `write()`.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, it has an API available already :)  Now just need to learn the methods.  Example request:

[root@servername php]# curl -qk "https:///services/rest/V2/?method=authenticate&username=&password=&format=json"
{"session_id":"07d68e681102200700f1aea46574f7"}[root@servername php]#